# Change language for date cck field of a webform in drupal7?

Tags: webforms, entities, datetime

Can we change language for date cck field of a webform in drupal7? 
If I create a component of date type in webform then drupal provides a dropdown having month,day and year values in English e.g. Jan 1 2013 , I want a drop down for this component having options in different language say spanish (witout using any translation module, I am translating webform manually) Is it possible?

Answer (score 0):

go to /admin/config/regional/date-time/locale/es/edit and change the date format to month first for the long, short and medium dates